Arduino Uno, TCA9548, BME280 - Not Found Sensors BME280
It is not recognizing the BME280, however, when I run the I2C Scanner, it finds them.... I have checked many times and I can't find any problem / solution.... Please help!
enter image description here
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1022)

Adafruit_BME280 bme1; // I2C
Adafruit_BME280 bme2; // I2C

// Select I2C BUS
void TCA9548A(uint8_t bus){
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x70);  // TCA9548A address
  Wire.write(1 << bus);          // send byte to select bus
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void printValues(Adafruit_BME280 bme, int bus) {
  TCA9548A (bus);
  Serial.print("Sensor number on bus");
  Serial.println(bus);
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());
  Serial.println(" *C");
  
  Serial.print("Pressure = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readPressure() / 100.0F);
  Serial.println(" hPa");

  Serial.print("Approx. Altitude = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
  Serial.println(" m");

  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(bme.readHumidity());
  Serial.println(" %");

  Serial.println();
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  // Start I2C communication with the Multiplexer
  Wire.begin();

  // Init sensor on bus number 0
  TCA9548A(0);
  if (!bme1.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 0, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println();
  
  // Init sensor on bus number 1
  TCA9548A(1);
  if (!bme2.begin(0x76)) {
    Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 1, check wiring!");
    while (1);
  }

}

void loop() { 
  printValues(bme1, 0);
  printValues(bme2, 1);
  delay(5000);
}

Serial output:
12:02:06.477 -> Could not find a valid BME280 sensor on bus 0, check wiring!

Scanner I2C results:
12:37:34.158 -> TCAScanner ready!
12:37:34.158 -> TCA Port #0
12:37:34.196 -> Found I2C 0x76
12:37:34.196 -> TCA Port #1
12:37:34.196 -> Found I2C 0x76
12:37:34.196 -> TCA Port #2
12:37:34.196 -> TCA Port #3
12:37:34.227 -> TCA Port #4
12:37:34.265 -> TCA Port #5
12:37:34.265 -> TCA Port #6
12:37:34.265 -> TCA Port #7

I need to get the values of those two BME280 sensors, I have the need to put 4 in total, but I have wired these two to test the process..... That is why I am using the multiplexer.

I'd use SPI, same pins for mosi, miso and sck, different pins for csb. Also crossposted on Arduino SE

What is the point of keep re-posting the question, while you are not clarifying/answering any of the questions/suggestions others have commented?
